# centos cannot delete a directory

Tags: linux, centos, directory, rm

I am trying to delete the directory 'dirr':

```
/package/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dirr/
```

I have tried rm -rf

```
sudo rm -rf dirr

rm: cannot remove `dirr': Directory not empty
```

When I check what is inside the directory,

```
[root@my_pc dirr]# ls
ls: cannot access __init__.pyc: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access __main__.py: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access __main__.pyc: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access _execution.py: No such file or directory

_execution.py  __init__.pyc  __main__.py  __main__.pyc
```

I have no idea what is going on.

Here is some extra information:

```
centos-release-6-6.el6.centos.12.2.x86_64

ls -al
?????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? _execution.py
?????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? __init__.pyc
?????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? __main__.py
?????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? __main__.pyc
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround:

```
mv -f /package/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dirr/ /tmp/
```

If it works, then you can just reboot and see if the directory is deleted (in many Linux distributions /tmp/ gets "cleaned" at boot, not sure about yours -- if not, then try to delete it manually from /tmp/).

Another possible workaround:

```
rm -ri /package/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dirr/
```

This will bring a question about deleting each one of the problematic files -- choose "y" and see if they get deleted.

If that does not work, try finding the inode of each file inside the folder and deleting it via inode, like:

`ls -li /folder/` example output: `918625 -rw-r--r ...etc`

and then delete each of the files with find:

```
find /folder/ -inum 918625 -delete
```

Comment: I tried a mv -f and it complains about the files inside the directory not existing..

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definite answer to your question, but I had a similar problem on CentOS recently -- I was seeing garbage for file stats on `ls`, just as you do.

Are your files residing on an `ext2` partition?